# Subclassing MKOverlayPathView to create MKPolylineView

Tags: ios, mapkit

Has anyone attempted to subclass `MKOverlayPathView` in order to, essentially, recreate `MKPolylineView` with more control of the path drawing? If so, would you be willing to share some example code?

I want to draw an `MKPolyline` on a map view but `MKPolylineView` does not offer enough flexibility in how the path is drawn. For instance I want to add a stroke and highlight on the line like the routes seen in the Maps app.

[image]

Comment: Have you come up with any solution?

Comment: If you come across any solution, share it here please, I am putting your question as my favorite ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this today when I was looking for a way to draw a border around an `MKPolylineView`. After a bit of research and digging around, I created my own simple subclass of `MKOverlayPathView` which works as a drop-in replacement of `MKPolylineView` and adds support for drawing a border.

It ended up being very simple, you can take a look at the sample code on GitHub [ASPolylineView](https://github.com/nighthawk/ASPolylineView) or take a look at my [brief blog post](http://nighthawk.github.com/blog/2013/02/21/drawing-multi-coloured-lines-on-an-mkmapview/) describing the main things that need to be done. It's a good building block to get started with more advanced custom drawing. For a more sophisticated subclass of `MKOverlayPathView`, take a look at [AIMapViewWrapper](https://github.com/cocoatoucher/AIMapViewWrapper/tree/master/AIMapViewWrapper/AIMapViewWrapper/Routing) - especially the `AIOverlayRouteView` class.